# Filter Sets tab not visible in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I am using Apache Superset 1.5.1, my account has the Admin role assigned and hence (among others) permissions

```
can delete on FilterSets
can add on FilterSets
can edit on FilterSets
can list on FilterSets
```

However, I do not see the tab "Filter Sets" in the filter panel and cannot find any option or system setting to enable it. I searched the list and description of `FEATURE_FLAGS` in the Superset source code but could not find anything that would fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to set feature flags `DASHBOARD_NATIVE_FILTERS` and `DASHBOARD_NATIVE_FILTERS_SET`.

However, it appears the `filter sets` feature is being removed.

https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/16818#issuecomment-1387308737
https://github.com/apache/superset/pull/23785

Comment: Thank you, DASHBOARD_NATIVE_FILTERS_SET was the missing feature flag. Not sure why the maintainers of Superset want to remove the filter sets though, creating "bookmarks" with preselected filters is a useful functionality, also existing in other data visualization solutions.